# React how to change button back to disabled when input empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate I am using the *isValid* state to check if input matches the rules

```
        <form>
          <Controller
            name="username"
            control={control}
            rules={{
              minLength: {
                value: 2,
                message:
                  'Tx',
              },
              pattern: {
                value:
                  /^([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)/,
                message:
                  'x',
              },
            }}
            render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
              <SecondaryInput
                name="username"
                errors={errors}
                innerRef={ref}
                {...field}
              />
            )}
          />

          <PrimaryButton
            disabled={!isDirty || !isValid}
            type="submit"
          >
            Test Submit
          </PrimaryButton>
        </form>
```

And it works:

1. Button is disabled (empty input)
2. I type
3. Button not disabled anymore

But when I delete everything (empty input) the button is not disabled.
The *isValid* state remains *true*

It is probably due to the *isDirty* state but I don't know how the code works without the isDirty state

Comment: Did you use the handleSubmit of react-hook-from in form tag?

Comment: Yes, just to log the data in the console. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The information that you gave is quite not enough. Make sure that you are using a function to handle changes to your input field using the `onChange` property. Use the `useState` function to declare and store the value of the user input and the boolean values `isDirty` and `isValid`.

On your function that handles the change to the input field, make sure to check whether the input is valid/dirty or not and update the boolean variables as needed.

Since you declared your variables with `useState`, react updates the state and your web page should behave the way you want it to.